# Retrieve 10 records from MySQL?

Tags: .net, asp.net, mysql, ado.net, paging

What is the logic to retrieve last 10 records from MySQL database in ASP.NET page?

Comment: `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`, like so many questions before this one...

Comment: @OMG - Couldn't find working one :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually fairly simple just use the following sql(id is the primary auto incrementing key you can use another field as long as that field is in order)

```
 SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: it is mandatory because the purpose is to fetch the last ten records

Comment: @Lobo, Prasanth - ya! its necessary in my case.

Comment: My bad, I just read the title of this question which didn't mention anything about last.